# An Egyptian citizen travelling to Kuwait with a valid Saudi resident permit

Tags: saudi-arabia, egyptian-citizens, kuwait

I am Egyptian citizen having valid Saudi iqama with me with good profession on iqama.

Can I fly to Kuwait without visa from my home country (Egypt) when I am on vacation? this is for business trip but unfortunately I will be on vacation this time. it's so  confusing.

Comment: https://www.dgca.gov.kw/ar/travellers/traveller-information/arrival-procedures/visa-services

Answer (score 2):

As an Egyptian citizen with a Saudi iqama then you can get a visa on Arrival IF:

1. travelling for tourism
2. You stay for max 3 months
3. Your passport and  iqama have at least 6 months left when entering Kuwait
4. You have return tickets and an address where you will stay in Kuwait.
5. You are a doctor, lawyer, engineer, teacher, judge, consultant, pilot, member of the public prosecution, university teacher, journalist, press/media staff, system analyst, pharmacist, physician, manager, computer programmer, businessman, diplomatic corps, owner/manager. representative of commercial companies, or a university graduate.

If all These conditions are fulfilled, you can get a free visa on Arrival (not enter without a visa - you still have to get a visa at a desk before immigration)